# JqGrid is not able to display data

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to display data in JqGrid from spring controller.
Here is the JSON response from my spring controller `{"rows":[{"firstName":"sharma","lastName":"sharma","id":2}],"page":"1","records":"1","total":"1"}`

This is my jsp file:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:'/url',
    colModel:[
      {name:'id', label: 'ID', formatter:'integer', width: 40},
      {name:'firstName', label: 'First name', width: 300},
      {name:'lastName', label: 'Last Name', width: 200}
    ],
    caption: "ReportingEmployees",
    pager : '#pager',
    height: 'auto'
  }).navGrid('#pager', {edit:false,add:false,del:false, search: false});
</script>
```

I have spent hours to figure out what is wrong, JSON looks valid also.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the option

```
datatype: 'json'
```

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/varun.htm) uses JSON data which you posted and your code where I added `datatype: 'json'`. It displays

[image]

Comment: @varun: Look at the demo from **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @varun: It's *the code which you posted*. You can just open the source of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/varun.htm) in context menu of the web browser. You can verify that [the JSON file](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/varun.json) contains *your data* only.

Comment: worked like a charm. There was a problem with jquery library version I was using. Thanks :)